# Save as feature using textfields into tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

In my app I want a save as feature. This means people will enter what they want their drawing to be saved as in a textfield and then those names will load up in a table view. How would I do this?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific while asking a question. Saving data depends on the app requirement, whether you want a persistant data or not. If you want to save large amount of persisent data, core data is a useful option, if you want to save small amount of persisent data you can use nsuserDefaults. If you want to save data locally in a view you can use an array or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In the view that you make the drawing, add a textfield and hook it up to an outlet. Then put a button next to that saying save. Hook that up to an ibaction. The ibaction should take the text from the field , so

```
NSString *s = [textfield text];
//get the data from your saved data as an nsmutablearry

[array addObject:s];
//save the array again.
```

Add that to an array and save it to NSDefaults, core data, or Archive it to a file. Then make another button saying something like "other drawings" and hook that to an ibaction. This action should present the table view controller.

```
Yourtableviewcontrollersubclass *vc = [[Yourtableviewcontrollersubclass alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The table view controller file should be able to recall the saved data from nsuserdefaults, core data, or archive depending on where you save it.